# How to create user defined type as a member variable in Scala class?

Tags: scala

How to represent this in scala SBT project?

Mainly I want to know how to create variable like public Out out; in scala as mentioned below in C#.

Thanks in Advance.

#### Home.cs

```
namespace AA
{
    public class Home
    {
        public In in{get;set;};
        public Out out{get;set;};
    }
}
```

#### In.cs

```
namespace AA
{
    public class In{}
}
```

#### Out.cs

```
namespace AA
{
    public class Out{}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "package" keyword in Scala is similar to "namespace" in C#. Refer to [Programming in Scala chapter 13](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/packages-and-imports.html) and search for "C#"...